# Why do I have so much Machop candy?

Tags: pokemon-go

So I finally caught my first Machop today...

I opened up my Pokemon, tapped on Machop, and the first thing I notice is that I have 21 Machop candies. How is this possible? He is the only Machop I've ever caught. What other way(s) could I have gotten all of this candy? Pokestops? Battles?

[image]

Comment: Did you hatch one?

Comment: Did you catch any of the evolutions? The candy is shared across all of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You hatched it.

Eggs will also grant a varying number of candies for your type of Pokemon. I have observed 15-25 or more candies upon hatching.

Comment: I can confirm less than 15. I hatched a Bulbasaur with only 11 candy.

Comment: i hatched 2 pikachu and i have 16 candy right now (without catching or evolving any)